# Is there a way to know that iOS keyboard is really hidden (dismissed by user)?

Tags: ios, ipad, uikeyboard

I need a way to detect the case when user dismisses iOS keyboard manually, using "keyboard" button on keyboard. I tried to use `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`, but quickly discovered that this event is also fired when user splits the keyboard, leaving it on screen.
Is there a way to know for sure that keyboard was really hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get solution I had to slightly modify my original implementation: I've replaced assigning `nil` to `inputView` member of my main view with creating and destroying custom invisible `UIView<UIKeyInput>` view to show and hide keyboard correspondingly. This allowed me to override this view's `resignFirstResponder` method which is **always** called on keyboard resigning - either in normal or in split state, when user dismisses keyboard using special button or when I remove it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` is only sent when the keyboard is truly gone. From the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html):

> Posted immediately after the dismissal of the keyboard.

However, you could also look to see if any of your inputs are currently the first responder:

```
BOOL keyboardUp = NO;

for (UIView *view in self.textInputs)
{
  if (view.isFirstResponder)
  {
    keyboardUp = YES;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` is also fired when the keyboard is split on iPad, although the docs don't mention this.

Comment: And in case keyboard is already split `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` is never fired when keyboard is dismissed.

Comment: For keyboard interaction I use custom `UIView` implementing `UIKeyInput` protocol which is always first responder. To show and hide keyboard I modify `inputView` member with `nil` or custom invisible view correspondingly.